# Can't call function within keyDown or keyPress event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Can't call function within keyDown or keyPress event handlers.

```
 var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var gamePattern = [];

$(document).on("keydown",  nextSequence);

function nextSequence() {
   var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
   var randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNum];
   return gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor);
}
```

Comment: unclear what you are expecting `return gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor);` to do passing it back to the event handler.

Comment: What is not working? What is supposed to happen that is not?

Comment: This code works, just insert a console.log inside and you can see it logs

Comment: When  I run  the code and press a key I expected the event handler to run the function but it doesn't work.

Comment: It runs the function. You just do nothing with the data in it.

Comment: It runs  @epascarello was right i did not use the data in it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You probably don't need the return since your variable is scoped outside of the callback.  As @Samathingamajig pointed out it's actually working.  You can also call the `keydown` shorthand version with

```js
$(document).keydown(function () {
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    var randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNum];
    gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor);
    // Check the current state of gamePattern
    console.log(gamePattern);

});
```